# How to solve for unknown variable with summation operator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

i had the following equation of which i need to solve for $p_0$. The expression is : $\sum_{m=1}^{M+1}[q_1(m)-q_0(m)]log_2[p_0q_0(m)+(1-p_0)q_1(m)]=\\\sum_{m=1}^{M+1}q_1(m)log_{2}q_1(m)-q_0(m)log_2q_0(m)-[q_1(m)-q_0(m)]log_2e$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side is just a constant, independent of $p_0$. call it $K$. On the left hand side, the expression can be simplified by letting $a_m = q_1(m) - q_0(m)$ and $b_m = q_1(m)$. And as its our variable, just call $p_0$ by "$x$" instead. The equation becomes
$$\sum_{m=1}^{M+1} a_m\log_2(b_m - a_mx) = K$$

If you raise $2$ to the power of each side, you get
$$\prod_{m=1}^{M+1} (b_m - a_mx)^{a_m} = 2^K$$

If all the $a_m$ happen to be integers $\ge 0$, this would be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $\sum_{m=1}^{M+1} a_m$. Which would mean that there could be as many as $\sum_{m=1}^{M+1} a_m$ different solutions for $x$. Or (if you want real solutions only), there could be no solution at all. Even when the $a_m$ are not subjected to such severe restrictions, these lessons still hold. Depending on the $a_m, b_m$, there could be many solutions or none at all.

Inevitably, when people ask this sort of question, they are wanting some formula $p_0 = ...$ written in terms of functions and operations the questioner is familiar with or can easily learn, and usually because the questioner thinks that this is *the* way to calculate values. But this hope is more often than not a chimera. One finds such solutions when learning mathematics because the problems you are given to solve have been intentionally limited to the tiny subset that actually have such solutions. But when you stretch your mathematical wings into the broader world, reality comes crashing in. Most problems do not have such "nice" solutions.

But there are alternatives. Root-finding schemes can be used to estimate solutions to any desired accuracy (and another real-life lesson: except when the solution is guaranteed to be integer, or a low denominator rational, you never actually get an exact solution, even when you do have a nice equation for it).

The gold standard for these is Newton's method. Let $$f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{M+1} a_m\log_2(b_m - a_mx) - K$$
and define
$$f'(x) = \log_2 e\sum_{m=1}^{M+1} \dfrac {a_m^2}{a_mx - b_m}$$
(This is the derivative of $f$. You listed "algebra precalculus", but I've just done the only calculus part, so all you have to do is precalculus.)

In Newton's method, you make some initial guess $x_0$ at a root, then repeatedly calculate
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
If you are not unlucky, this will quickly approach a constant value that will be an actual solution to your equation. Which solution it will converge to is dependent on your initial guess.

Comment: I am trying your solution but getting wrong value of x i.e. p_0 (optimal probability).

Comment: There are a few possibilities. If it is settling in on a single value $x$, but that $f(x)$ is not close to $0$, then there is an error in the math somewhere (whether yours or mine). If it is settling in on a value where $f(x) \approx 0$, but it isn't the solution you are after, then you need to make a different starting guess. If it is not settling in on a single value of $x$ at all, then it could be either math errors again, or else the method failed (it can do that). But in that case usually a better initial guess will work.

Comment: I checked my calculation of the derivative, and realized it should have been division by $\ln 2$ instead of by its inverse $\log_2 e$. So it is multiplied by $\log_2 e$ instead. See if that works better for you.